How do I change an enx(mac_address_here) ethernet port to be usb0?
I have a network of Ubuntu NUCs (between 20 and 30). They are all running Ubuntu 20.04, except for one that I have just installed 24.04 on to, as it tried to end itself.
All of the 20.04 NUCs interact with their own external device connected over a usb cable. They all have usb0 as the ethernet name on the usb port. This is how I talk to the external devices using Rundeck.
The new NUC, running 24.04, shows the usb0 port as enx############ where #### is the link/ether address (without the colons).
As my Rundeck job searches for the usb0 interface, this NUC's external device doesn't receive the instructions.
Is there a way that I can change the enx... name to permanently be usb0?
I have googled, but I keep finding answers regarding a usb drive, not a usb0 ethernet port.
I have manually written the netplan file 01-dhcp-enx.yaml (it is called dhcp, even though the ip addresses are static. It is a flowover from a previous configuration). I have written this port as enx###... but as Rundeck only looks for usb0, this doesn't solve my problem.
I am able to ssh into this NUC using enp5s0 (with a static ip address). I am unable to ping the external device from other NUC's on the network, but I can ping other external devices from this NUC.
When I do an ip a, I get lo(I assume this is the loopback), enp5s0(used to connect to the laptop with Rundeck), eno1(used to access the internet when disconnected from the main network) and enx############ (used to connect to the external device.)
The other NUC's all have this same ip a output, except they show usb0, not enx...
I have spent many an hour trying to resolve this, so any input would be greatly appreciated.
This is my first question, so apologies is the format is poorly done.

We started using predictable names:

Starting with v197, systemd/udev under Linux automatically assigns predictable, stable network interface names for all local Ethernet, WLAN and WWAN interfaces. This is a deviation from the traditional interface naming scheme (eth0, eth1, wlan0, ...), which should solve previous problems.

To revert:
sudo vi /etc/default/grub

Find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX and add
net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0

Then do
sudo update-grub

and reboot.

Thank you very much. That did exactly what I needed to do. I would up vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet. I have marked it as the correct answer, though.
